# What is the proper way to request this entity? Python and GQL

Tags: database, google-app-engine, entity, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I'm trying to see if the username variable in the post function matches the username in the accountsArchive entity.

I think the problem is that user.username isn't the proper way to reference the username entity. Also, the query above may have a problem. What's the proper way to see if the two usernames match?

## Python

```
class accountsArchive(db.Model): 
    # The username entity
    username = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    password = db.TextProperty(required = True)
    email = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    dateJoined = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class loginPage(Handler): 
     def post(self): 
        # The username variable
        username = self.request.get("username")
        password = self.request.get("password")

        # The query
        user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM accountsArchive WHERE      
                            user.username = :name", name=username)
        
        # This is how I tried to check if the two usernames matched
        if username == user.username: 
            # Do stuff
```

Comment: Far too much code for any one to wade through.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep this in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems in your code.

Firstly

```
user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM accountsArchive WHERE      
                        user.username = :name", name=username)
```

Is incorrect - you should go back and reread the docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference?hl=en

This query should be

```
user = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM accountsArchive WHERE      
                        username = :name", name=username)
```

Next.

The result of this line of code is an instance of GqlQuery class not a user or as you might expect a list of users.  See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass?hl=en

You now have to fetch the results and/or iterate through them.

For instance

```
for u in user.run():
    if u.username == username:
       # then do something
```

However you have a problem.  There is nothing in this that would limit the system a single unique user.  So if you get more than one user with the same username what will you do.

Some comments.

You could use the username as the key of the accountsArchive which means you just use a get rather than a query.

Secondly if you are new to appengine and don't have an existing base of code, start out using ndb instead.

Comment: Didn't know about .run() before. Thanks!